# Two lines aligned left and right have bigger vertical spacing than following <div>

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to place two consecutive lines with half the text aligned left and half aligned right and after them another paragraph. I'm trying like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>HTML Page</title>
    <style>
        .left {
            float: left;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div>
        <p class="left">Left align.</p>
        <p class="right">Right align.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <p class="left">Left align.</p>
        <p class="right">Right align.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ligula neque, tempus ut dictum in, feugiat non sem. Nam ultricies cursus sodales. Duis est justo, hendrerit non accumsan vitae, rutrum vel elit. In quis elit purus. Aenean nec massa elementum, laoreet augue sed, gravida felis. Nullam nec faucibus nisl. Donec vel nunc vitae justo auctor placerat ut eu purus. Duis ut porta felis. Fusce mollis, nibh a cursus consectetur, lorem metus lobortis felis, ac gravida sapien purus non enim. Nam pharetra dolor nisi, in scelerisque eros fermentum ut. 
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there is a bigger vertical spacing between the first two lines than between the second line and the following `<div>`.

Do you know how to solve the problem, or another way to obtain the expected result? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just because your p tag has this top and bottom margin and on the other side, the div with bigger content does not have the top margin.

Solution: remove the top-margin from p tag. See eg below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>HTML Page</title>
    <style>
    p{
    margin-top:0;
    }
        .left {
            float: left;
        }
        .right {
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div>
        <p class="left">Left align.</p>
        <p class="right">Right align.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <p class="left">Left align.</p>
        <p class="right">Right align.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;" >
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ligula neque, tempus ut dictum in, feugiat non sem. Nam ultricies cursus sodales. Duis est justo, hendrerit non accumsan vitae, rutrum vel elit. In quis elit purus. Aenean nec massa elementum, laoreet augue sed, gravida felis. Nullam nec faucibus nisl. Donec vel nunc vitae justo auctor placerat ut eu purus. Duis ut porta felis. Fusce mollis, nibh a cursus consectetur, lorem metus lobortis felis, ac gravida sapien purus non enim. Nam pharetra dolor nisi, in scelerisque eros fermentum ut. 
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```